# mysql increment based on criteria

Tags: mysql

Basic question of language ability.

I am developing a database to keep track of market trades and provide useful metrics to the user. Most brokers do not supply enough information in the transaction .csv file which would be imported to this database to combine strategies and positions in a useful way, or in a way that I envision can be useful for users. For instance, combining a buy order on AAPL of 1000 shares that was filled in three separate transactions on the same order (1 order for 1000 shares filled initially with 200, then 350, then 450 shares). I could only think of assigning a trade group to each of these so that I can group them.

So, the example above, each transaction would be a separate record, I've created a column in my table with the alias of Trade Group, and each transaction would be assigned 1 under the Trade Group column. The sale of the 1,000 shares, no matter how many transactions it took to fill the order, would also be assigned to trade group 1.

My query combines the shares for both opening and closing transactions by using the trade group and transaction type (buy or sell). If there is a match, 1,000 shares on the buy side, and 1,000 shares on the sell side, then it runs some queries to provide useful data about the trade.

The problem I foresee is that the trade grouping can become cumbersome since it currently has to be manually input. I would like to develop a counter to automatically increment the trade group of each the opening and closing transactions every time the balance of shares = 0.

So if both the buy and sell of the above example belonged to trade group 1, and now I decide to open up a position of 2000 shares of AAPL, and subsequently sell them, those transactions would be automatically assigned trade group 2. And now that the balance of shares is 0 again, the next time I open and close a position on AAPL it will be assigned trade group 3.

That way, I don't need to clutter up my table with something that is manually input which can create mistakes. Instead, the query assigns the trade grouping every time it is run, and the necessary metrics supplied.

Is this something that can be done using SQL alone?

Thanks.

[image: Transactions Table]

Comment: You would need sql triggers with IF cases to facilitate the auto assignment of groups id.

Comment: I think its possible, but I need more visual db for that. Can you display the tables that you use, and the results that you want (in which situation which line is inserted).

Comment: I added the transactions table, it's made up of a few other related tables that really aren't pertinent. The trade group column (and the strategy group column, but both function similarly so if I can do it with one I can do it with the other) has to be manually input. I would like to do away with that. I would like them to be grouped via a query instead. Right now, I group by Transaction Type, Position, Underlying, and Trade Group. I feel Trade Group is necessary, but it is not necessary to have have it on the table, and hope it can be generated by a query.

Comment: Also, I'm not asking to generate the code for me, I'm not that lazy.. lol. I just want to know if it's possible to do with SQL, or do I need to use another language to do it, like php